# How to remove rows from a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix of shape (25,10) it could also be any other number than 25 I want to remove excess rows and get  matrix of  shape (20,10)

Comment: Check the docs to learn how to slice and index numpy arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
# Let's say your matrix is stored in a variable called "my_matrix"
# then you can do something like this:

my_matrix = my_matrix[:20] # equals to: my_matrix[0:20]

# or:

my_matrix = my_matrix[2:22]

# or if you are using numpy:

indices_to_keep = np.asarray([...indices of elements you want to keep...])
my_matrix = my_matrix[indices_to_keep]
```